# cant undrstand the error :Access denied for user 'Pratik'@'localhost' (using password: NO) got in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

firstly i just clearify the problem.
i am testing the page of login of my website.
so i have two login files for testing that both contain same code but both are save in different place named "signin.php" & "login.php" resp.

the problem is when i try to login from "signin.php" which located in root folder(www) gives an error:Access denied for user 'Pratik'@'localhost' (using password: NO).in this i use session.

when i try to login from "login.php" which is located in "c:\Temp\" folder runs sucessfully. & create session of username as per my code.

now i try "signin.php" again for login, then this time it login sucessfully.
but when session expire. & i try to login from "signin.php" again it show above error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that you are accessing the database with `username: Pratik` and an empty password.

It won't connect without any password.

Comment: actually my db username is root & no password

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("Admin") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Gaaaah. Do NOT use 'root' as your database account. NEVER EVER USE ROOT AS YOUR DATABASE ACCOUNT. Create a new user with just the privileges you require for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `mysql_connect()` (or `mysqli_connect()`) statements. If you're using that in multiple places, obviously one or more of them differ somehow, most likely by a variable not being in the proper scope. For instance:

```
$user = 'Pratik'
$host = 'localhost';
$password = '...';

function db_conn() {
    global $user, $host;
    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
}
```

This will fail as you have no declared $password to be global within the function, so you'll get a blank password and "Using password: NO" for an error.

Comment: as i told you my other login file works fine.
& my username is root  .
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("Admin") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

This is because your document root is set to 
`c:/Temp/` not the default `c:/xampp/htdocs`(in case of xampp) or `c:/xampp/www/`(in case of WAMP).

To change it go to `c:/xampp/apache/httpd.conf` or where ever your apache is installed. Search for the Document root and set to to desired path.

Hope this was helpful.. :)